# find a driver to Hp Deskjet 2721e

Tags: drivers, wireless, software-installation, lenovo, hp

Getting this printer/scan, I can'get the right driver : on HP links, downloading failed. Computer LeNovo G 50-30, ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Did you install hplip?

Comment: Yes, downloading was right (but very slow), but opening failed

Comment: What do you mean by "opening failed"?